# Table with only one column because of many-to-many relationship?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, denormalization

Right now I have three tables: `person`, `alias`, and `person_alias`. As suggested by the names of tables, one person can have multiple aliases and one alias can be used by many people, and hence I add a joining table `person_alias` during the process normalization.

However, the table `alias` essentially only contains one column (if I do not choose to use numeric surrogate key). In addition, let's say the table `person` also contains a bunch of other useful information that is irrelevant to the question here.

I am not a bit stuck at justifying setting up the entity relationship map this way. What is the problem that I delete the table `alias` all together? Or do I misunderstand many-to-many relationship/normalization?

Comment: The alias in this scenario is not an entity. It doesn't have any attribute, and even if it did, these attributes must be shared among the persons that use the same alias to justify being an entity. In that sense alias as a table is not justified.

Answer (score 0):

The `alias` table will save space because you do not repeat duplicated aliases in the `person_alias` table.

If in most of the cases aliases are unique, then this won't matter much, but if you have a lot of duplicated aliases (say every second person uses `'Zaphod Beeblebrox'` as a alias) then this could save a lot of space.

However, if you allow a single person to rename their alias without affecting all other (duplicated) aliases, then removing the `alias` table completely could makes sense.

You could de-normalize further and store all aliases for a person in an array column in the `person` table removing the `person_alias` table as well. But in that case it will be quite complicated to define a unique index that ensures that every alias is unique for that person. If you (almost) always retrieve all aliases for a person together with that person that *might* be slightly more efficient.

But if you want to ensure uniqueness of the aliases per person in the database, stick with the `person_alias` table.

Comment: Yes I am assuming all aliases in the `alias` table will be unique. Keeping the table `alias` will only save space under the assumption that "storing a varied length of string is averagely more expensive than storing an integer", right? If we assume, that all aliases are two-character string, is there still reason to keep the table `alias`?

Comment: @kumom: **if** all aliases are unique, **and** your aliases are indeed only two character string, then yes the `alias` table won't help much.